# How to convert .tff images to CCITT4 format

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I got the new image successfully, but I can't get the original image, the image was cropped.
Here is the code I tried:

```
private byte[] ConvertToCCITT4(byte[] input)
{    
    MemoryStream memoryStream1 = new MemoryStream(input);

    RasterCodecs.CodecsPath = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName;
    RasterCodecs rasterCodecs = new RasterCodecs();
    using (IRasterImage irasterImage = rasterCodecs.Load((Stream)memoryStream1))
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream();
        rasterCodecs.Save(irasterImage, (Stream)memoryStream2, (RasterImageFormat)29, 1);
        return memoryStream2.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share if you have solution for this.